# MySQL Order By parent/child and name

Tags: mysql

How can I query information from a table, using MySQL, to return information ordered by the table in a type name and parent type.

As an example, I would like to take a table such as this one:

```
+---------+-------------+------------+
| type_id | parent_type | type_name  |
+---------+-------------+------------+
|       1 |           0 | Type 1     |
|       2 |           0 | Type B     |
|       3 |           0 | Type 3     |
|       4 |           3 | Sub Type 1 |
|       5 |           0 | Type 5     |
|       6 |           0 | Type 6     |
|       7 |           3 | Sub Type 2 |
|       8 |           0 | Type C     |
|       9 |           1 | Sub Type 1 |
+---------+-------------+------------+
```

And then use a query to pull it out like:

```
+---------+-------------+------------+
| type_id | parent_type | type_name  |
+---------+-------------+------------+
|       1 |           0 | Type 1     |
|       9 |           1 | Sub Type 1 |
|       3 |           0 | Type 3     |
|       4 |           3 | Sub Type 1 |
|       7 |           3 | Sub Type 2 |
|       5 |           0 | Type 5     |
|       6 |           0 | Type 6     |
|       2 |           0 | Type B     |
|       8 |           0 | Type C     |
+---------+-------------+------------+
```

Basically making it so the child rows come after the parent row and ordering the parents by type name.

So far this is as far as I've been able to get with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `item_types` AS b 
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN `parent_type` = 0
        THEN `type_id`
        ELSE `parent_type`
    END,
    type_name;
```

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You have a self-referential table ... so you will need something like

```
select id, parent_id, name
  from (select type_id as id, type_id as parent_id, type_name as name
          from item_types
         where parent_type = 0
        UNION
        select type_id as id, parent_type as parent_id, type_name as name)
          from item_types
         where parent_type != 0)
 order by id, parent_id, name
```